# Bootstrap DropDown and collapse dont work with angular2-meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, meteor, angular2-meteor

I install bootstrap in my angular2-meteor project with:

```
meteor npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5
```

then dropdown and collapse component dont work, but when i add bootstrap scripts lines in my index.html body then my bootstrap component work fine.

Why

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: No, nathing in my meteor console nether in browser console

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use Bootstrap 4 CSS with Angular 2 I would suggest evaluating one of libraries that provide native Bootstrap widgets: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io

Those widgets are written specifically for Angular 2 and offer APIs that make sense in context of Angular 2. Since the library was written from ground-up for Angular 2 you won't need dependency on jQuery nor any Bootstrap's JavaScript (it is enough to include Bootstrap's CSS and the mentioned library)